# Downloading Files with PHP

Tags: php, apache, mysqli

I am having some trouble downloading files with php on apache server. When the file is requested it does return and download, however, when trying to open the file it says that the file might contain invalid characters. I tried the code on the php.net site and still get the same response. My question is there something I'm not doing or doing incorrectly? My php code is below.

```
        //result is filename from db
    if($result){
        $row   = $database->fetch_array($result);
        $file_name = '../uploads/'.$row['filename'];
        if(file_exists($file_name)){
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            readfile($file_name);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual for PHP header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), it appears you are specifying the file name for the end user along with the relative path for the server.

Try changing this line;

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");
```

To;

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$row['filename']\"");
```